# Use JSON file to insert data in database

Tags: javascript, json, mongodb, meteor

I'm using my JSON file like this to insert data in my collection :

```
 var content = JSON.parse(Assets.getText('test.json'));
        console.log('inserting...');
        Profiles.insert({
            user: id,
            data:content
        };
```

But I would like to have a "data's tree" like that :

```
[
    user: "rtegert23423131",
    firstname:"test",
    surname:"test2",
    // ...
]
```

Not like that :

```
[
    user: "rtegert23423131",
    data:{
        firstname:"test",
        surname:"test2",
        // ...
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple use underscores [`_.extend`](http://underscorejs.org/#extend) function. Like this:

```
var newProfile = _.extend(
  JSON.parse(Assets.getText('test.json')),
  {user: id}
)

Profiles.insert(newProfile)
```

Answer (score 0):

using underscore

```
var content = JSON.parse(Assets.getText('test.json'));
  _.extend(content, {user: "rtegerkjxxx"})
 console.log(content) //to make sure you're saving data
 Profiles.insert(content)
```